# why django model can't save my new object when i click create button in 'create.html'

Tags: django

I'm beginning to use Django, and I have some problems. I want to create new post such as blog. So I use views.py with model.py and forms.py.
but when I enter the create.html, I was writing what i want to post, and then click 'create' button. but it wasn't save in django object. I check in admin site, but there is no object. I think it means save object is failed. but I don't know where is the problem. plz help me T.T

in views.py

```
def create(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        filled_form = ObForm(request.POST)
        if filled_form.is_valid():
            filled_form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    Ob_form = ObForm()
    return render(request, 'create.html', {'Ob_form':Ob_form})
```

in create.html

```
<body>
    <!-- form.py 모델 생성 -->
    <form method="POST" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}}
      {{Ob_form.as_p}}
      <input type="submit" value="확인" />
    </form>
  </body>
```

in models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Ob(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

in forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Ob

# 모델폼을 상속받아서 모델폼이 되었음
class ObForm(forms.ModelForm):
# 어떤 모델과 대응되는지 말해줌
    class Meta:
        model = Ob
        fields = ( "title", "image", "content")

# 모델 폼 커스텀
# init - 내장함수 - (해당 클레스에 들어오는 여러가지 인자를 받을 수 있는 파라미터)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].label = "제목"
        self.fields['image'].label = "사진"
        self.fields['content'].label = "자기소개서 내용"
        self.fields['title'].widget.attrs.update({
            'class': 'Ob_title', 
            'placeholder': '제목',
        })
```

and urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import index, create, detail, delete, update


urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name="index"),
    path('create/', create, name="create"),
    path('detail/<int:Ob_id>', detail, name="detail"),
    path('delete/<int:Ob_id>', delete, name="delete"),
    path('update/<int:Ob_id>', update, name="update"),
]
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of guesswork here, but it's probably the case that `filled_form.is_valid()` is returning false, which will mean `save()` is never reached. To test this simply, just put an `else` and `print` on the `if`.

```
if filled_form.is_valid():
    filled_form.save()
    return redirect('index')
else:
    print("Form validation failed")
    print(filled_form.errors)
```

It's likely that you'd also want to return these errors to the user in the future, which means you'll need to make a couple of changes.

Right now, regardless of whether `ObForm` validates successfully, you are creating a new instance and passing that to the user. My typical approach would be to declare the form variable at the top of the function, and if it isn't already set when it comes to render the view, create a new instance of the form then. This way, if the form was populated by the user already (i.e. the request was a POST) then the errors will be returned with their input, instead of clearing their input (which is really annoying from a user's point of view!).

As a side note, I'm going to guess that you submitted a form with empty image and content fields, and were expecting that to be stored in your database? Try changing your field declarations to:

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

`null=True` tells the database to allow null values, but `blank=True` tells the form validation to allow empty values.